# Need to Validate Time Range Overlaps when Creating new Appointment

Tags: vb.net, validation, time, range, appointment

How can I validate the time that overlaps when creating new appointment?
I have a method (below code), but I can't validate if the time I choose is not overlapping the existing day on that same date.

```
mycn.Close()
mycn.Open()
'Done na
Dim SQLQuery As String
SQLQuery = ""
SQLQuery &= " SELECT StartTime,EndTime,Date FROM tblAppointment" & vbCrLf
SQLQuery &= " WHERE ((cast(Dateadd(minute,+1, @StartTime) AS time) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime) AND Date=@Date AND PatientID=@PatientID)" & vbCrLf
SQLQuery &= " OR ((cast(Dateadd(minute,-1,@EndTime) AS time) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime) AND Date=@Date AND PatientID=@PatientID) " & vbCrLf

Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SQLQuery, mycn)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", dtpDate.Value.ToString("MM dd, yyyy"))
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartTime", cmbStartTime.Text)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("EndTime", cmbEndTime.Text)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientID", lblPID.Text)

Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader
If dr1.HasRows Then
    MsgBox("Appointment Existing", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Appointment")
    cmbStartTime.SelectedIndex = -1
    cmbEndTime.SelectedIndex = -1
    cmbEndTime.Items.Clear()
    cmbEndTime.Enabled = False
    Exit Sub
Else



    'MsgBox("No Record Exist.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "New Leader Record")
    ReservationDataGridView.Rows.Add(lblID.Text, lblPID.Text, lblPatientName.Text, dtpDate.Value.ToString("MM dd, yyyy"), cmbStartTime.Text, cmbEndTime.Text, cmbServiceType.Text, Val(lblPrice.Text))
    PatientGridView.Enabled = False
    txtPatientSearch.Enabled = False
    iD()


    Dim total As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To ReservationDataGridView.RowCount - 1
        total += ReservationDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value
        'Change the number 2 to your column index number (The first column has a 0 index column)
        'In this example the column index of Price is 2
        txtSubTotal.Text = total
    Next
End If

mycn.Close()
```

Comment: Storing dates in your DB as text is never a good idea because they wont act like dates.  Pretty much the same with your times - BETWEEN may not work right `10:00` will not be between `9:15` and `11:00` because it is text.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I have a trouble in the logic for this transaction on how i can validate the time. @Plutonix